# Resetting Google's data for the website

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I own a domain which I was using for experimenting with different platforms and content management systems. I really did not care about seo while I was building the website so I guess my website has quite a 'bad reputation' for Google search. My website is almost finished and I am planning to launch it soon but would like to tell Google to forget everything it nows about it and start everything over.

What's the correct way for doing it? I found [Requesting reconsideration of site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843) but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure it's necessary? Bad repuation requires you did some outright nasty black hat seo and spam'ish stuff, and not just poor design, adding/removing pages etc.

Most likely, all problems with google will resolve themselves over time as they crawl your content and good backlinks to it.

Answer (score 0):

This article http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734 should help. However I couldn't find the tool they mention under site diagnostics, so they may have taken it away. Using robots.txt to indicate invalid pages should help anyway, even if you can't make them remove urls until they get round to crawling you again.

Comment: I need to remove not only some pages but I also want Google to 'forget' everything it knows anything about it so that I can start everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a sitemap xml file and submit it to google and put it in the root directory. I recommend using sitemap writer pro.